# core_1.NgModule is not a function

Tags: angular

I'm using angular 2 rc-4 version, I,m facing an error "core_1.NgModule is not a function",i have surf through net,got few suggestions n made few changes in package.json,like ng2-translate:2.2.2, but no use, i still get the same error.

Comment: It's impossible to help you without seeing your source code.

Comment: You need to update angular to RC.6